# How to clear cache in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In the docs I've learned that I can clear cache by including `cache: {}` into my gitlab-ci.yml file like so:

[image]

I must be using it wrong though because this is what I read in build output:

[image]

I've got problem with this because few lines down I replaced `npm ci` with `npm install --no-optional` and the GitLab runner keeps calling `npm ci`

Any suggestions ?

Dockerfile:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

FROM node:11.12.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm install --no-optional
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent --no-optional
ARG REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL
ENV REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL $REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV


COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

`docker` cache and `gitlab-ci` cache are different things.

Lines you point out in red are lines produced during `docker build` command. Gitlab-ci [cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) option is used to specify a list of files and directories which should be cached between jobs.

To avoid using cache during `docker build`, use `--no-cache` option (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for more details)

Comment: The `npm ci` is still being called even though it's nowhere in my project. I'm using the `--no-cache` flag but no effect.

Comment: could you copy the content of your `Dockerfile` in your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

To clear the cache in GitLab CI, click the "Clear runner caches" on the CI/CD Pipelines page. This increases a counter in the cache key, effectively using new caches for everything.

See also this issue: [Clearing the cache (#41249) · Issues · GitLab.org / GitLab FOSS · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41249)